# iPhone: message sent to deallocated instance error

Tags: iphone, nsstring, nsdata

I have narrowed down this error (which crashes my app):

```
-[NSConcreteMutableData release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6eaed40
```

to the following code:

```
emailData = [kmlDoc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But, I cannot figure out why this error is being caused?  That line is just setting a very large string to an NSData object.  I am releasing emailData in the dealloc method.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Ok, it looks like removing emailData from the dealloc method fixes the issue.  But why?  Does NSData autorelease?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to take ownership of the object:

```
emailData = [[kmlDoc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] retain];
```

Or using retain/copy properties:

```
self.emailData = [kmlDoc dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Remember that you explicitly have to take ownership for returned objects from methods that contain neither `new`, `alloc`, `retain` or `copy` in their name as they return autoreleased instances.

See the [Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1) for more.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this up.  I used self.emailData and it solved my issue.